# How to get in lacs,in thousand,in crores in iReport (Jasperreport)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

While creating bar charts in iReport Some bars has high value, so the iReport bar chart automatically adjust the length as per the value. So the values on the value axis should be adjusted.

I would like to show in lacs, in thousand, in crores as per the values adjustment.